# Adding button in Magento 2

Tags: admin, template, magento2, magento2-dev-beta, customer-address

I'm trying to add button in customer address form. But I don't know how to do it from `customer_form.xml` file. If any one knows please suggest me.

[image]

I have registered button control on `ui_definition.xsd` and `ui_components.xsd` file but still it's showing like `textbox` instead of button.

**My Code is**

**Magento/Ui/etc/ui_definition.xsd**

```
<xs:complexType name="definition">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>Registering components in the system and basic setup</xs:appinfo>
            <xs:documentation>Registering components in the system and basic setup</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:all>
            <!-- Components list -->
            <xs:element type="tab" name="tab"/>
            <xs:element type="dataSource" name="dataSource"/>
            <xs:element type="paging" name="paging"/>
            <xs:element type="massaction" name="massaction"/>
            ..... etc
            <!--Custom Button Start-->
            <xs:element type="button" name="button"/>
            <!--Custom Button End-->
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
```

**Magento/Ui/etc/ui_components.xsd**

```
<!--Custom Button Start-->
    <xs:complexType name="button">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ui_element">
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:group ref="configurable"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <!--Custom Button End-->
```

and I have created Class `Button.php` from `Magento/Ui/Component/Form/Element`

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element;

/**
 * Class Button
 */
class Button extends AbstractElement
{
    const NAME = 'button';

    /**
     * Get component name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getComponentName()
    {
        return static::NAME;
    }
}
```

and finally I have created field from `customer_form.xml` file

```
<field name="button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">button</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Running without errors but it's showing textbox instead of button. Could you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Comment: I had tried to keep button code directly into the `magento2\app\code\Magento\Ui\view\base\web\templates\form\components\collection\preview.html` file. after execute grunt for backend its seem as `button`. Have you tried it ?

Comment: @PrafulRajput, I ran after installing grunt. it's returning error **Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'magento2-develop'
Warning: Task "exec:backend" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.** when i ran `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-develop>grunt exec:backend`

Comment: Command seem fine. You are neaer around your solution now. Are you using `master` or `develop`  branch? No matter , please run `composer update` command.

Comment: @PrafulRajput, I ran same command after updated composer still same error.

Comment: have you follow http://gruntjs.com/getting-started for grunt ? Because there might be some issue from grunt installation. Please install it proper and then try.
you can try `grunt exec:all`

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html please read here about grunt installation and its uses.

Comment: @PrafulRajput, i have ran after installing all grunt installations finally I got **Error: grunt exec:backend Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: _.each is not a function  Running "clean:backend" (clean) task >> 0 paths cleaned. 
Done, without errors. Gathering css/styles-old.less sources. Successfully processed dynamic stylesheet into CSS Gathering css/styles.less sources.
Successfully processed dynamic stylesheet into CSSDone, without errors.**.

Comment: Empty your pub/static/ (do not delete .htaccess). Refresh your browser. Error should not be come there while you execute grunt. Please resolve your grunt issue. `php bin/magento setup:static-content-deploy`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30715/discussion-between-magento-two-and-praful-rajput).

Comment: @PrafulRajput, thanks for given valuable suggestions now my custom button is showing. But `JavaScript` not executing could you please suggest me how can i do this. my code is: ` <div style="display:inline; float:right;  width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <button style="" class="scalable go" type="button" id="say"><span>Say Hello</span></button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $("#say").click(function() {
                    alert('Magento 2');
                });
            });

        </script>
    </div> `

Comment: For more information look @https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2170

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure it is correct way but it worked for me

app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/form/components/collection.html

```
<li class="address-list-item" data-bind="css: { 'ui-state-active': element.active }, click: activate">
          // put your code here
```

but best way is not change directly here you can override this file in your custom module.

do not forget to flush cache folder as well as static content and run `grunt exec:backend` command after change this file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. after modifying `collection.html` file I run `grunt exec:backend` command but it's returning **grunt is not recognize internal or external command error**.

Comment: First you must install npm and grunt tool. http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: I ran after installing grunt. it's returning error **Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'magento2-develop'
Warning: Task "exec:backend" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.** when i ran `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2-develop>grunt exec:backend`

Comment: confirm you have package.json and Gruntfile in your root folder and and after completing all steps given in above link you should have 'node_modules' folder in your root folder and all grunt plugins should installed in it which are defined in package.json.

Comment: Generatefile.js, package.json and node_modules folders are created and installed all grunt commands after that I got **Error: grunt exec:backend Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: _.each is not a function  Running "clean:backend" (clean) task >> 0 paths cleaned. 
Done, without errors. Gathering css/styles-old.less sources. Successfully processed dynamic stylesheet into CSS Gathering css/styles.less sources.
Successfully processed dynamic stylesheet into CSSDone, without errors.**.

Comment: thanks for given valuable suggestions now my custom button is showing. But `JavaScript` not executing could you please suggest me how can i do this. my code is: ` <div style="display:inline; float:right;  width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;">
        <button style="" class="scalable go" type="button" id="say"><span>Say Hello</span></button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $("#say").click(function() {
                    alert('Magento 2');
                });
            });

        </script>
    </div> `

Answer (score 4):

Sorry that this is not a complete answer but more a pointing in the "right" direction.

There are a set of elements that can be called inside the `Magento/Ui` system. These can be found under `app/code/Magento/Ui/Component/Form/Element/`.

Here by default you will see:

1. Checkbox.php
2. Input.php
3. Multiline.php
4. MultiSelect.php
5. Radio.php
6. Range.php
7. Select.php
8. Textarea.php

These elements are set-up in the definition file `app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml`. For example the checkbox looks like the following:

```
<checkbox class="Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/boolean</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/checkbox</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</checkbox>
```

From what I can see from my quick looking around it should be possible to add your own type via this sort of definition, though I am not sure about the workings. You will need to add your own element template here, the defaults can be found under `app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/*.html`

You can see that the definition.xml file is added via di as follows:

```
<virtualType name="uiDefinitionFileCollector" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\FileCollector\AggregatedFileCollector">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="searchPattern" xsi:type="string">etc/definition.xml</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

So you should be able to add your own definition.xml file to your module and it will be picked up.

Sorry this is not a complete answer but it should be a good start in the "right" direction.

Comment: thanks for answering. I will get back to you after I tried.

Comment: I have updated as you instructed and it's running without errors but it's showing textbox instead of button. I have updated my post please look on that.

Comment: @magentotwo did you add the definition for the element template?

Answer (score 0):

I have written today a simple way of implementing your requirement using mixins.

to setup the mixin, create a requirejs-config.js file in your view/base folder of a module that will host the mixin

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection': {              
            'Mbs_AddButtonInCustomerAddressForm/js/address/collection':true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in the js file defined in the mixin above: you may overwrite the template so that it does use a template in your module

a sample of the js file is below:

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (addressCollection) {
        const orig = addressCollection.defaults;
        orig.template = 'Mbs_AddButtonInCustomerAddressForm/collection';
        orig.buttonExtraLabel = 'Click Me';

        return addressCollection;
    }
});
```

finally in the custom template, you can add the button.

This solution will not touch the core file from Magento and therefore you will remain compliant with further releases from Magento

I have a full code repository showing how to do the url keys and url rewrite at: https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/addbuttonincustomeraddressform