# Unable to extend adminhtml customer addresses tab in magento2

Tags: customer, adminhtml, magento2, customer-address

In magento1 i could extend the adminhtml customer addresses tab

```
class Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Addresses extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Addresses {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('vlcsolutions/customer/tab/addresses.phtml');
    }
}
```

and now if i modify `vlcsolutions/customer/tab/addresses.phtml`, changes are reflected,

How to achieve the same in magento2.

I have not found any class or template like customer/tab/addresses.phtml

Comment: Is this question only so you can answer the bounty question? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87428/158

Comment: Do we get any update on latest release on GA?, Still i have not found any solution...

Comment: For more information look @https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2170

Answer (score 1):

These pages are using the new `Magento/Ui` module. The UI is defined for use in the layout file `app/code/Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml`. Here you can see the line:

```
<uiComponent name="customer_form"/>
```

This will tell Magento to use the UI from the file `app/code/Magento/Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`

Now this file can see complex at first appearance, and also at second appearance, but it is split into different sections.

For example the fields to show on the address form are defined under the node `<fieldset name="address">`.