# how to extend/inject this to customer address in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, php-5.4, customer-address, uicomponent

I'm trying to extend customer address page, but it's overriding. I want to inject in the middle of the address tab form.

My Code is:

**Learning/CustomerAddress/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "learning/CustomerAddress",
    "description": "Customer Address",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-customer": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Learning\\CustomerAddress\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**Learning/CustomerAddress/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Learning_CustomerAddress',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Learning/CustomerAddress/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_CustomerAddress" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Learning/CustomerAddress/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml**

0
                    Learning_Custom/form/my-template

**Learning/CustomerAddress/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/my-template.html**

```
  <h1>Magento 2 Customer Address </h1>
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="test();">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        alert('Click Me!!!!!');
    }
</script>
```

Now it's showing my button, when I clicked on that it's not taken action.

[image]

Could you please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: @SohelRana, Any suggestions/help?

Comment: I want to inject in middle of the tab how to do it? -> What does it mean? could you share your screen?

Comment: @SohelRana, actually i'm trying to do like [this thread](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87131/adding-button-in-magento-2). But I think directly inject the button is not possible. So, I'm planning to create a separate custom module then inject those customization without disturbing like you created [AdditionalShippingBlock](https://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/how-to-add-custom-field-to-shipping-address-form-in-magento-2-onepage-checkout/) Custom Module.

Comment: @SohelRana, did you get a chance to look on my thread?

Comment: Sorry, Nope @magento two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved my self by fallowing below steps:

**Learning/CustomerAddress/view/base/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection':  'Learning_CustomerAddress/js/form/components/collection'
        }
    }
};
```

**Learning/CustomerAddress/view/base/web/js/form/collection.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiRegistry',
    'uiComponent',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
], function (_, utils, registry, Component, layout, confirm) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            lastIndex: 0,
            template: 'Learning_CustomerAddress/form/components/collection'
        }

    });
});
```

**Learning/CustomerAddress/view/base/web/template/form/components/collection.html**

```
<div>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.sendAddress.bind($parent, element)">
        Click Me!
    </button>
</div>
<br/>
```

Comment: You've essentially replaced the core capabilities with your custom collection.js.  Watch out if you upgrade.

Comment: @CarComp If you have better solutions please post your answer.

Comment: Sure... I'm working on the same problem. I'll post below.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @magento two's answer, I've managed to find a way to somewhat extend the `web/js` objects while still maintaining the original `JS` object's constructors and functions are available.

I've done this by adding a `RequireJS` map of the core module name (internal to Magento, in this case it is a string "`Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract`") that points to my custom `Javascript`.  This is exactly what @magento two did.

Although this works, I've commented that the core code at the path "`dir/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract.js`" never gets loaded.  To fix this, rather hackishly I'll admit, is to add a `RequireJS` path variable that points to the magento core `Javascript` file.  I then inject it into my custom js (which initializes the core file, and gives me access to all of its properties / methods etc)

I extended adminhtml, but you could easily apply this to base, or frontend.

**MyCompany/MyModule/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js**

```
var fullHost;
if (!window.location.origin) {
    fullHost = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port: '');
} else {
    fullHost = window.location.origin;
}


var config = {
    paths: {
        "originalAbstract": fullHost + "/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract"
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            default:    'Stti_Customer/js/default',
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract':  'Stti_Customer/js/default'
        }
    }
};
```

**MyCompany/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/default.js**

```
define(['jquery','originalAbstract'], function($, Abstract) {
"use strict";

return Abstract.extend({

    /**
     * Invokes initialize method of parent class,
     * contains initialization logic
     */
    initObservable: function () {
        // Add jquery event observers observers
        debugger;
        switch(this.index){
            // Do things related to the current object's name
        }

        this._super();

        return this;
    }
});
```

});

This workaround is probably due to an interesting conflict between **Zend's** "**Where it is, is What it is, is What it does**" naming `conventions` vs `RequireJS` module names.  I'll also admit there is *probably* a better way to get the Filename for the core `Javascript` file, but I'm not there yet!

Comment: I will back after I tried

Comment: fixed a bug assigning fullhost using the else statement.  You have to have it for it work. Also added this._super(); call.

Comment: Hi the above two files is enough or I need to add my files also?

Comment: You will need your files to make the button work.  Also, I'm working on a knockout implementation that will handle the click events.  I think jQuery is not the right approach.  I'm working on it.

Comment: Ok, that's great. I will tried as your approach and back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can expand an existing fieldset by adding Magento Ui Component Container. If you will look at `Magento/Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`, you can find an example of container usage:

```
<container name="street_container">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">group</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Street Address</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">street</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">45</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    ...
</container>
```

To extend fieldset "address" you can add container your container as a child element of the fieldlist. Also you can define sort order of this conatainer (I put it just after the Street container):

**Learning/CustomerAddress/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="address">
        <container name="custom">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">46</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Learning_Custom/form/my-template</item>
                </item>

                <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Item</item>
                        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: great work. It's working fine. But I want to insert a button on same location and when user clicks I want to call **custom controller** with parameter `address_id`. Can you please tell me how to do it?.

Comment: see my above thread. any help/suggestions?

Comment: I think you can add button in customer_form.xml (I've updated my answer). Also you can find more details at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97291/explanation-of-ui-component-grid-in-magento-2

Comment: it's creating button on top of the form. I'm created button inside the address form see my thread image. When I clicked on button just send the address_id to controller. that's it.

Comment: I've seen [your another question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87131/adding-button-in-magento-2). As there is no UI Component  'Button', you should try to create your own. Or find out a workaround with button in a template and add scripts to procced this button

Comment: thanks for helping. I have solved by modifying core files that core files placed in my theme, now working fine. If you have solution to implement through **find out a workaround with button in a template and add scripts to procced this button** plz.. post here..

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with your button. Just change the this.index in the case statement to YOUR buttons name.