# What js is used when add new customer address in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, adminhtml, customer-address

In Magento 2 when create new customer, there is address tab and when i click new address there is a js running that render the address field, but i don't know which one, i want to extend that js so i can insert my custom function from my extension,

Here's the figure of add new address and inspect element:

[image]

when i click add new address there are 2 files which triggered by js, and i want to know what js that calls them

**EDIT**

i've tried add mixin, requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection': {
               'NamespacE_Module/js/form/components/collection-mixin': true
            }
        } 
};
```

collection-mixin.js :

```
    /**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
    return function(collection){
        var newFunction = collection.addChild;
        var newFunction = wrapper.wrap(newFunction, function(original){
            //do extra stuff
            console.log('before');
            //call original method
            var result = original();
            console.log('after');
            //do extra stuff

            //return original value
            return result;
        });

        collection.addChild = newFunction;
        return collection;
    };

});
```

the function i want to add is after **addChild** function which is the original function from collection.js

Comment: is it working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override `Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection.js` file in your Module.

and your `requirejs-config.js` file should be below

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

    var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection':'[Namespace]_[VendorName]/js/form/components/collection'
            }
        }
    };
```

in your `collection.js` file and update below code.

```
sayHello:function(){
            alert('simple guy')
        },

        /**
         * Creates new item of collection, based on incoming 'index'.
         * If not passed creates one with 'new_' prefix.
         *
         * @param {String|Object} [index] - Index of a child.
         * @returns {Collection} Chainable.
         */
        addChild: function (index) {
            this.childIndex = !_.isString(index) ?
                'new_' + this.lastIndex++ :
                index;

            layout([utils.template(childTemplate, this)]);

            this.sayHello();

            return this;
        },
```

after completing this,

you need to remove `pub/static/adminhtml/` and `pub/static/_requirejs/adminhtml/`.

and run the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.

finally open one of customer page try to click on **Add NewAddress**.

let me know if you have any info.

Comment: when i click the add new address button i got this error `[Namespace]_[VendorName]/js/form/components/collection/item.js 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @simpleguy can you post your code so that we will find where you went wrong.

Comment: i just copy the entire collection.js, i think the problem is in requirejs-config, because in the same folder with collection.js there is a folder named collection which contain item.js inside

Comment: @simpleguy Hmmm please update your question with your code. Other wise we can't help.

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: @simpleguy update full path file and full of code and what is your assumption to implement here?

Comment: @simpleguy if you want any example look at here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98262/how-to-extend-inject-this-to-customer-address-in-magento-2 my answer.

Comment: the above example is override the original function, i want my function to be triggered after the original function, see my updated question

Comment: @simpleguy your function should call after **add newAddress** button click or ?

Comment: after add new Address button clicked it will render address form, i want my functron run after that form rendered

Comment: @simpleguy see my updated answer

Comment: in collection.js should i copy all the code from the original file and change it or just the above code?

Comment: @simpleguy copy all code to your file and just declare above simple method and call your function in `addChild` function.

Comment: there is an error saying item.js not found, because it search the file from my extension directory not from the original directory

Comment: @simpleguy Yes now seems to be working. create **collection** folder inside **components**  folder copy paste the `item.js` file from `Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection` along with create `tab.js` inside **compnent** folder and copy paste the `tab.js` file from `Magento_Ui/js/form/components/tab.js`. Finally remove static folder `adminhtml` and `requirejs` and then apply `php bin/magento setup:static-conetnt:deploy` command

Comment: @simpleguy Is it working?

Comment: @simpleguy was it working?